# How to Retry RxAndroidBLE Discover Services in case of GATT error.

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-java2, rxandroidble, bluetooth-gatt

I am using RxAndroidBLE library for discovering services in my GATT server. 
it works fine most of the time but often i get GATT error 133 (0x85) and it fails. I will like to retry for discovery of the service couple of time for a time period, say for 5 seconds. 
here is the code i am trying

```
bleDevice = mBleClient.getBleDevice(macAddress);
    subscription =  bleDevice.establishConnection(false)
            .flatMap(RxBleConnection::discoverServices)
            .first() // Disconnect automatically after discovery
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnUnsubscribe(this::onUnsubscribe)
            .compose(this.bindToLifecycle())
            .retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> {
                        if (isGattError(error) {
                            return Observable.just(new Object());
                        } else {
                            return Observable.error(error);
                        }
                    }
            ))
            .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(this::getScanResult, this::onConnectionFailure);
```

Its not working and looks like the retryWhen is not getting called. It may be more of  rxJava issue but i will really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Hello @Avijeet — are you sure that the connection and service discovery will finish successfully in those 5 seconds?

Comment: what i have observed is that when it works it take only a second or two for service discovery.  5 seconds time interval can be changed , the main problem is how to retry .

Comment: What do you do in `.onUnsubscribe()`?

Comment: onUnsubscribe i just      if(subscription != null) {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }

Comment: i also unsubscribe in connection failure as well

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying, since retryWhen will retry all the things above it so onUnsubscribe gets called as well and it will kill the connection..  if i don't do anything in onUnsubscribe then it should work .. right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote in the comments your `this::onUnsubscribe` is calling `subscription.unsubscribe()` so the `.retryWhen()` operator has no possibility of being called.

You could move the `.doOnUnsubscribe()` below of `.retryWhen()` or the other way around to give get the intended behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Dariusz, i have another small question for you, can we try the retryWhen approach for connectionObservable as well ? i face same issue(error 133)  in preparing Connection Observable as well.

Comment: Yes, `RxBleDevice.establishConnection()` is ready to work with `.retryWhen()`. The only problem with `.retryWhen()` is when it is used on `Observable`s obtained from the `RxBleConnection` and the connection itself will be disconnected — those observables when retried will return the disconnection exception. To continue a new connection needs to be established.

Comment: Do you have an example where we can handle exception and retry for connection. i have been observing that some time there is a garbage collection happens which cause BLE gatt to be disconnected, and then my code keeps waiting to connect and read from my ble device.

Comment: I do not get the garbage collector part but the retry when is used for instance in the [advanced sample activity](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble/sample/example4_characteristic/advanced/Presenter.java) which you may check out.

Comment: Thanks Dariusz. I have tried various approach for RetryWhen in connection Observable. Once connection gets disconnected it does not work again. i will try some other approaches as well. if it does not work then may be i will post a separate question. But as always thanks for quick and timely help.

Comment: FYI I'm going on two week holiday so I might be unresponsive during that time.

Comment: Since the RxAndroidBle2 release, here is the updated link for the [advanced sample activity](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble2/sample/example4_characteristic/advanced/Presenter.java).